# Google Script : Sending Hangout Messages using Script

Tags: google-apps-script, message, send, google-hangouts

Is it possible to send Hangout messages to someone using Google Scripts.

If there is, can you post an example script that shows the sending of Hangout Messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chat used to use XMPP which may have done but Hangouts uses its own proprietary protocol. https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2013/05/google-abandons-open-standards-instant-messaging

There has recently been a 3rd party reverse engineering project for the protocol - a python library - which you could fork for GAS but like all such projects it is unsupported Google and therefore subject to any change in the protocol.

https://github.com/tdryer/hangups/

Comment: Hello sir , I am trying to uinderstand this reverse engineered protocol implementation , but I am getting stuck at some points , could you please help me out ? invite sent on hangouts .

Comment: I know nothing about it other than the link i googled for you above.

Comment: You should remove the `It isn't` sentence. After reading your answer I feared I won't be able to achieve my goal but thanks to Hangups it's perfectly possible! Yes, it is 3rd party, it is reversed engineered but it works!