# Send notification to Hangout from Google AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker, google-hangouts

Does anyone had tried to send a notification to Google Hangout from Google AppMaker? Usually, I use the `MailApp.sendEmail` to send the notification to Gmail. But this time, I wanted to pop-up a notification directly to the user's Hangout. How can I achieve that using Google AppMaker? Is there any API to do so?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Classic Hangouts [isn't supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952789/1422413) by Apps Script, and [Hangouts Chat bots](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/quickstart/apps-script-bot) don't have an API for sending messages to an individual user, only a room. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714972/google-hangouts-chat-bot-to-send-dms-via-incoming-webhook) may help in providing a workaround.